# Reducer is adding items in the store out of nowhere

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, reducers

So I am trying to add a cart feauture to my React-redux site and I got stuck on a very weird occurance. So this is what I get from the payload of the action for example:

```
{
    info: 'Fjallraven - Foldsack No. 1 Backpack, Fits 15 Laptops',
    id: 1,
    price: 109.95,
    image: 'https://fakestoreapi.com/img/81fPKd-2AYL._AC_SL1500_.jpg',
    count: 5,
    totalPrice: 549.75
 }
```

So what Im trying to do is, when an item with the same id as this one is trying to be added, to not add it, but to increase the count of the item with the same id that already exists in the cart:

```
const index = state.currentCart.findIndex((x) => x.id === id);
return {
          ...state,
          currentCart: [
            ...state.currentCart,
            state.currentCart[index].count += 1,
             (state.currentCart[index].totalPrice =
              state.currentCart[index].price * state.currentCart[index].count), 
          ],
        };
```

The count itself is increased, but there is something really strange happening at the same time.
The total price of the product and its count are also added as elements of the currentCart array, when the only thing that should happen is to update the count of the cart item with the id from the payload,
this is what happens to the currentCart array when this action is fired:

```
currentCart: [
    {
      info: 'Fjallraven - Foldsack No. 1 Backpack, Fits 15 Laptops',
      id: 1,
      price: 109.95,
      image: 'https://fakestoreapi.com/img/81fPKd-2AYL._AC_SL1500_.jpg',
      count: 6,
      totalPrice: 659.7
    },
    2,
    219.9,
    3,
    329.85,
    4,
    439.8,
    5,
    549.75,
    6,
    659.7
  ]
}
```

I am sure I am not mutating the state right, thank you in advance!

Comment: You are talking about the strange values in `currentCart` array? like `2, 219.9,`

Comment: Yes, exactly, it just appears out of nowhere, or I am doing something wrong.

Comment: try removing this line in your `return` statement and try again `(state.currentCart[index].totalPrice =state.currentCart[index].pricestate.currentCart[index].count),`

Comment: Hey, I am sorry i had the return wrongly coppied, I fixed it, can you take a look again

Comment: hmmm... try wrapping your setting calling inside a `{}`. `currentCart:[...state.currentCart,{state.currentCart[index].count += 1, and remaining setter}]`.

Comment: I don't think this is a viable syntax actually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, they are not coming from nowhere, you are actively adding the values to the array.
You seem to be a bit confused about how to properly handle states. You either choose an immutable approach (which I really recommend if you are using react) or you choose to mutate your references.

In javascript, when you do an assignment, that assignment also returns the value that is being assigned, so for example here:

```js
let x = 1
let b = x+=1
// b is now 2 and x is 2
let c = b += 2
// b is now 4 and c is also 4
```

That is exactly what is happening on your array assignment. You are first spreading the old version of the array on the new one (making a copy) and then you mutate the reference to the current car at the same time (and this is the key part) that you are saving the return value of those assignments in the array itself.
Take a look at the values on the array, they are the results of your operations:

```
count (1) += 1 // 2
price (109.95) * count (2) = 219.9,
count (2) += 1 // 3
price (109.95) * count (3) = 329.85
... etc
```

So what you have on your array is an historic of the count and total price values.

This is a breakdown of what is happening in your code:

```
// Will allways be at index 0, because you add it as first element 
// and then you keep copying the array below
const index = state.currentCart.findIndex((x) => x.id === id); 
return {
          ...state,
          currentCart: [
            // Here you are copying the old array into the new one,
            // keeping the current car at the first position 
            ...state.currentCart,
            // Here you are updating the values of the object at index 0
            // and at the same time you are adding those values at 
            // the end of the array
            state.currentCart[index].count += 1,
             (state.currentCart[index].totalPrice =
              state.currentCart[index].price * state.currentCart[index].count), 
          ],
        };
```

What you want to do is to build a new currentCart each time and. Also you want to use an object for currentCart, not an array. If you want to keep a list of items in the cart, I suggest you tu create a nested property on the cart called items, and make that be an array.
Your code example is not showing us where are you getting the action from, but I will provide you an example assuming you just have it and that the new item to add to the cart comes in the payload.

```
  const currentCart = state.currentCart;
  const newItem = action.payload
  return {
      ...state,
      currentCart: {
        ...currentCart,
        count: currentCart.count + 1
        totalPrice: (newItem.price * newItem.count) + currentCart.totalPrice,
        items: [...currentCart.items, newItem] 
      },
    };
```

Comment: currentCart is originally an empty array in the initial state, but you are returning it as currentCart: {} in the action, this is the thing I don't understand in your example, can you explain, please.

Comment: You should change currentCar to be an empty array in the initial state. The way you are using it does not make sense for it to be an array. An array is to have a list of items, but currentCar looks like it's a single entity, therefore you don't need an array. I'll fix the code to remove all the array references.

Comment: Its an array because I then use it in a component with .map to load the cart items

Comment: You will have to share more details about your code, but if you want it to be a list of current cars (which you never explained) you better name it in plural. Also, the code you show us is not adding new cars to the array, it is just updating the first one

Comment: Dude, you keep saying CARS, its CART, the thing in an online shop that you put your items you want to order in :D

Comment: Maybe you read it wrong, I mean I want to add items to the CART of the website and each item in this CART is a different product(object)

Comment: Oh, yeah, I definitely read it wrong. Then there is something missing in the code you posted. You are not adding a new item, the piece of code you posted is just updating the cart. What you want probably is to get a new item, then add them to the list of items on the cart and then, update the total with the values from the new item. I'll try to add a small example to showcase this.

Comment: If you are finally happy with the answer @Chrissisbeast can you accept it?

Comment: I ended up doing it another way, but I will still mark it as solution, because I appreciate that you took the time to explain and show me what I was doing wrong :)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but this is happening
totalPrice = item's price * no of times the item is added

Other items' price is not getting included. Try this -

```
state.currentCart[index].totalPrice += state.currentCart[index].price * state.currentCart[index].count
```

(just '+=' instead of '=')

Comment: It was like that originally, then I changed it to '=' they both give the same result...